# Office 356 REST API for search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, rest

Office 365 REST API for search return only 500 rows by setting parameter **rowimit=500**.
This is the query i am trying..
https://server_address/_api/search/query?querytext='test'&rowlimit=500

but when i try to extend the limit to more than 500, I was getting following error
[image]

Is there any way to extend the limit to more than 500 rows?
Where can we find the documentation for REST API for SharePoint search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Search limits for SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-limits-for-SharePoint-Online-7c06e9ed-98b6-4304-a900-14773a8fa32f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) SharePoint Online search has the following limit:

```
Limit:     Number of rows in a result set
Maximum value:  500        
Limit type: Boundary(*)        
Notes: To display the entire result set, issue more paging queries
```

> **Boundary** - A number that can’t be exceeded

---

Since 500 `RowLimit` cant be exceeded you could consider the following approach to return all search results. The idea is to perform queries until *all* search results will be returned, for that purpose we will utilize `RowLimit` and `StartRow` query parameters.

```
function search(webUrl,queryText,rowLimit,startRow,allResults)
{
    var allResults = allResults || [];
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + queryText + "'&rowlimit=" + rowLimit + "'&startrow=" + startRow;
    return $.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
           var relevantResults = data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults;
           allResults = allResults.concat(relevantResults.Table.Rows);
           if (relevantResults.TotalRows > startRow + relevantResults.RowCount) {
               return search(webUrl,queryText,rowLimit,startRow+relevantResults.RowCount,allResults);
           }    
           return allResults;
    });
}
```

Usage

```
search(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'sharepoint',500,0)
  .done(function(results){
       for(var i = 0;i < results.length;i++){
           console.log(results[i].Cells[3].Value);
       }
   });
```

### References

[SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete documentation for the REST API (AFAIK).

1. Did you try it with 499?
2. You could implement a paging (get the first 500 and then skip the first 500, etc)

The [search query tool helps](http://melcher.it/s/3P) you creating those queries easily.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to get more than 500 records without iteration. Do we have any option to get bulk amount of search rows?